# In wpgeodirectory add event how to make mandatory the field to connect event with place (business link)

Tags: wordpress

The business link (Place) is not mandatory when inserting a new event. How to make this mandatory. Every event should be connected with a place !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Visuals

   Add class "required_field" and * in the respective Business Link row by replacing this at plugins\geodir_event_manager\gdevents_template_functions.php   line 1035

   ```
       <div id="geodir_link_business_row" class="geodir_form_row clearfix">
         <label>
         <?php _e( 'Link Business', 'geodirevents' );?>
         </label>
   ```

   with

   ```
       <div id="geodir_link_business_row" class="required_field geodir_form_row clearfix">
         <label>
         <?php _e( 'Link Business', 'geodirevents' );?>
             <span>*</span>
         </label>
   ```

in the same function replace also

```
<input type="button" id="geodir_link_business_autofill" class="geodir_button button-primary" value="<?php echo EVENT_FILL_IN_BUSINESS_DETAILS; style="float:none;margin-left:30%;" ?>"
</div>
```

with this

```
<input type="button" id="geodir_link_business_autofill" class="geodir_button button-primary" value="<?php echo EVENT_FILL_IN_BUSINESS_DETAILS; ?>" style="float:none;margin-left:30%;" />

<span class="geodir_message_note"><?php _e('Basic HTML tags are allowed', 'geodirevents');?></span>
<span class="geodir_message_error"> <?php _e("This field is required","gdevents") ?>  </span>

</div>
```

2. Functional: prevent form from submit

a. deactivate listing_validation.min.js and enable listing_validation.js in
                \plugins\geodirectory\geodirectory_template_tags.php line 198

i.e. change this

```
wp_enqueue_script('geodirectory-listing-validation-script', geodir_plugin_url() . '/geodirectory-assets/js/listing_validation.min.js#asyncload');
```

to this

```
wp_enqueue_script('geodirectory-listing-validation-script', geodir_plugin_url() . '/geodirectory-assets/js/listing_validation.js#asyncload');
```

b. add the check in plugins\geodirectory\geodirectory-assets\js\listing_validation.jsline 159 (validate_form())

```
if (jQuery('#geodir_link_business')[0].selectedIndex == 0) {
    jQuery('#geodir_link_business').closest('.required_field').find('.geodir_message_error')[0].style.display = "inline";
    is_validate = false;
} else {
    jQuery('#geodir_link_business').closest('.required_field').find('.geodir_message_error')[0].style.display = "";
}
```